# (Java Swing GUI) How to make methods wait for input from buttons?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, wait

EDIT: NEVER MIND EVERYTHING I SAID!!!

I just realized that there's no need to use loops at all. Each method that sets up the GUI ends right after it finishes doing so, and the entire program "waits" for me to press a button after that. I just need to set up the methods so if necessary, they can "loop".

I'm not sure I'm explaining it correctly, but I think it's going to work. Thanks for the help anyways!

Just one more question, to be safe: when I set up the main window in the "main()" method, the program will only exit if it hits a certain condition that I've set up (i.e the player dies), and will not "end" on its own?

---

Ok, so here's my problem:

I'm working on a very primitive RPG that uses Swing as its GUI. Since this means I need a huge load of methods to make it work, and I need to control everything with a small amount of buttons (to keep things simple), I decided to use only a set number of buttons, and create several different ActionListeners. When a certain method is called, it sets up the GUI by setting the necessary number of buttons to "visible", setting their text, and assigning the right ActionListeners to them.

Here is an example (the player fights an NPC):

```
public int Combat(NPC e){
    game.setButtons(0, true, "Attack", 1);
    game.setButtons(1, true, "Ability", 1);
    game.setButtons(2, false, "", 1);
    game.setButtons(3, false, "", 1);
    game.setButtons(4, false, "", 1);
    game.setButtons(5, true, "Flee", 5);

    while(e.gethp() > 0 && this.hp > 0){
        if (!game.getProceed())
            break;

    }
    if (e.gethp() <= 0)
        return 1;
    else if(hp <= 0)
        return 2;
    else return 3;
    }
```

("setButtons":)

```
public void setButtons(int b, boolean v, String s, int act){
    button[b].setVisible(v);
    button[b].setText(s);
    switch(act){
        case 1: button[b].addActionListener(comlist[b]); break;
        case 2: button[b].addActionListener(maplist[b]); break;
        case 3: button[b].addActionListener(loclist[b]); break;
        case 4: button[b].addActionListener(invlist[b]); break;
        case 5: button[b].addActionListener(mainlist[b]); break;
        case 6: button[b].addActionListener(playlist[b]); break;
        case 7: button[b].addActionListener(intlist[b]); break;
        case 8: button[b].addActionListener(proc); break;
    }
}
```

(the "CombatListener":)

```
class CombatListener implements ActionListener{

    int but_num;

    public CombatListener(int n){
        but_num = n;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        player.CombatAction(but_num);           
    }

}
```

(The other listener I set up is the "Proceed" listener. This sets a boolean "proceed" variable in the game to false. The idea here was this would be my "back" button, that would allow me to get back from a menu to the previous one, or in this case: flee from the battle. This is why I set it up in that while loop, but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it.)

I'm not sure how much code I should provide for this to make any kind of sense (the whole thing is incredibly huge). If necessary, I'll post all of it here.

My question: How do I make sure that when my program enters the "Combat" method, then it will be able to stay there while I give commands using the buttons? The complication here is that these buttons often make the program enter an additional method, which could also set up the GUI in a different way, and when these methods complete, the GUI needs to be "reset" to work with the previous method.

I hope all of that made sense... :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what the problem is. You need to be clearer with the problem.

Comment: @trashgod It won't let me delete it...

Comment: My mistake; see this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/163188).

Answer (score 2):

In a SWING application you have no control over the so called "main loop".

Therefore, in a SWING application you don't do things like "wait for user input, process, loop".

SWING applications are "event driven" or "state machines" as you prefer. You must set up event handlers to deal with user input, then, given input X or Y, your application must evolve it's state accordingly.

For example, suppose a turn based combat game. During the player's move the application is in "player move state", during an enemy's move it is in "enemy move state". In "player move state" the application will offer interaction, then react to the user's choice, than transition to "enemy move state", then something else happens etc. After entering "player move state" and before the user's input there is no method active, no loop blocked on read or write. The application is "idle" waiting for some handler to become active.

Answer (score 0):

If your method is invoked via a button press, send that event to your ActionListener where you should have set your conditions to show the desired buttons when that event is triggered.

```
void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    btn1.setVisible(true);
    btn2.setVisible(true);
    btn3.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, pressed the wrong button and didn't post everything. Full "version" up now